# Execute blazor header OnInitialized on every page navigation

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side app. It has a common header for all pages. Inside the header's OnInitialized, it checks whether the user has any new messages. If so, it will blink an icon. This code of course will be executed once when the site loads. However, for each subsequent navigation to different pages, it won't execute again.

Is there a way to re-execute this every time a user navigate to whatever page? I understand I could also use a timer in the background to do this, but wondering if it's doable simply by page navigations?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should consider different solutions for this. Check out [SignalR with asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1) There are plenty of tutorials out there on how to implement this.

Comment: I am getting same issue, My dynamic header bind getting  called every navigation. Could anyone suggest best way to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options which should work on Server Side and on client side as well.

1. According to [Blazor docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#uri-and-navigation-state-helpers) you can subscribe to **`LocationChanged`** event. You can do it anywhere where you can get a reference of **`NavigationManager`**.

> The following component handles a location changed event by subscribing to NavigationManager.LocationChanged.

2. You can **override `OnAfterRenderAsync`** Blazor method on your **`MainLayout.razor`** page. **Since this is a shared layout component it will be rendered every time when App navigates.** You can even `@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager` to check which page rendered.

Code example for option 2:

```
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager
@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        var url = _navigationManager.Uri;
        //write you code here...
    }
}
```

**Probably option 2 is the best way to use since your code will run on a rendered UI so you have elements to change.**

Answer (score 0):

If you server side, why not all InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged) in case a new message is there.

So do in your *.razor code section:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    MyBackendService.OnUpdate += OnUpdate;
}

private void OnUpdate()
{
    // May be additional code to load the message - if requred
    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);        
}
```

And in the BackendService where the new message arrives or is created:

```
public event Action OnUpdate;
internal void UpdateView() => OnUpdate?.Invoke();
```

And now you can call UpdateView() in case there is a new message, like a callback to the view for reloading.